# grant select on view

Tags: oracle, select, database-schema, sql-grant

somewhere along the way something is going wrong, and I can't seem to find out why. If this is already asked apologies.

I have 3 schema's in my database:
COLLDESK
LOCAL_IT
GERBEN

COLLDESK is our main schema, LOCAL_IT is where we do our local development, and GERBEN is the end user (should only have select options).

Now I have a table in my COLLDESK schema called GESTIONES. In LOCAL_IT I have a view called ACTIONS. This is holding 4 columns from the table GESTIONES in the COLLDESK schema. So far so good!

Now I want to give the GERBEN schema select privileges in the view ACTIONS. But when I say

```
grant select on LOCAL_IT.ACTIONS to GERBEN
```

I get the error ORA-01720: grant option does not exist for COLLDESK.GESTIONES

Now I tried giving GERBEN select privileges to GESTIONES, but I am still getting the error message

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Gerben

Answer (score 22):

The error message should be written like this:

ORA-01720: "grant option" does not exist for COLLDESK.GESTIONES.

Here's how it works:

You have 3 schemas:

- Schema1 - Holder of a table named "table1"
- Schema2 - Holder of a view "view1" selecting from schema1.table1
- Schema3 - User, selecting from schema2.view1 - has no select granted on schema1.table1.

You probably have done the following:

```
grant select on schema1.table1 (COLLDESK.GESTIONES) to schema2;
```

Note that since you're creating a view, the select must granted directly to schema2, your view won't work if the select is granted through a role.

Now you are trying to allow a 3rd schema (schema3) to use the view read data from schema1. For security purposes, a schema2 will never be allowed to access data from schema1 to a 3rd schema even if it can view the data. This would be a huge security hole otherwise.

So the solution is to make it explicit that schema2 will be able to grant that select privilege, indirectly, when a 3rd party is granted the select privilege on the view.

Solution:

```
grant select on schema1.table1 to schema2 with grant option;
```

Now schema2, is allowed to grant select on its view to 3rd parties:

```
grant select on schema2.view1 to schema3;
```

For you:

```
grant select on COLLDESK.GESTIONED to LOCAL_IT with grant option;
grant select on LOCAL_IT.ACTIONS to GERBEN;
```

Also:
Avoid using public views and public db links unless absolutely necessary. Deplete every other options first.

Answer (score 1):

create a public synonym for the view and try again with your grants

```
create public synonym ACTIONS for LOCAL_IT.ACTIONS;

grant select on ACTIONS to GERBEN;
```

Comment: I am getting the Missing keyword error when I am trying to run your first query.

Comment: Had to change some other things. I had to run the query grant select on gestiones to local_it with grant option before I could grant the select to GERBEN. Thanks for your help anyway, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For the end user without having access to the view structure

```
grant select on COLLDESK.GESTIONED to LOCAL_IT with grant option;
create synonym LOCAL_IT.VWACTIONS for LOCAL_IT.ACTIONS;

grant select on LOCAL_IT.VWACTIONS to GERBEN;
```

It's works

Answer (score 0):

For the end user without having access to the view structure

```
create public synonym  V_ALERT_001 for usr_sms.V_ALERT_01 (lacal view );
grant select on V_ALERT_001 to USER_ALERT;
```